# .ByTruncatingHead works the way truncatingmiddle should have when numberoflines is 0 for UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

[image: truncating head works as if it was truncating middle]

Code to reproduce this:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 70)
        label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
        label.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Why do we use it?            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of ed since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        label.textColor = .black
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

[image]

The question is how would I get the multiline text head clipped as
opposed to the linebreakmode apply to the last line only?
Is there a way around this uikit deficiency?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code (or screenshots of your storyboard if you set up the truncation there) in the form of a [mcve]. How could anyone help without seeing your actual code that's causing the issue?

Comment: done, see if it has enough info and if it does not i'd appreciate if you vote for resurrection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is that with a truncating policy, a UILabel breaks the text at word-end, and then, if the text is too long for the label, *the last line* displays an ellipsis at the start, middle, or end of the line respectively, and text is omitted at the point of the ellipsis.

So in fact your code does not behave the same way as `byTruncatingMiddle`, which puts the ellipses in the *middle* of the last line. Your code puts the ellipses at the *start* of the last line.

Comment: but then it's pretty useless in my case cause the labels in my case are pretty narrow - they detail the 55x55 thumbnail collection view cells

Comment: and head and middle are aliased. what's the point besides the ease of implementing truncatehead for uikit deveopers?

Comment: That’s not a question. What you consider to be useless or what the point is, is not at issue. Here we deal in facts. These are facts.  This is how it works and how it always has worked. If you don’t like it, don’t use UILabel.

Comment: i have an annotation plus (optionally) some $$$$ value at the end which obviously takes precedence over the description. I surely could blame the designer but that's not terribly helpful or responsible course of action.

Comment: ok, so I'll back off and rephase: how could I achive the true bytruncatinghead: to have it apply to the whole body of the text. As the name of the option seems to imply.

Comment: Never mind “name” and “imply”. What did I say? This is how it works.  If you don’t like it, don’t use UILabel. If you want to lay out the text yourself, do so. You will have to use TextKit. Good luck.

Comment: I guess I'll take path of the cowards and castrate the prefix in a random way myself then appending the valuable suffix crossing the fingers hoping this to work. Textkit seems to be the path of a righteous man and expensive at that.